# How much damage does my weak wizard's dagger do?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, damage, ability-scores

My wizard's strength is 5 which means his mod is -3, and I don't add proficiency to my damage/type section, so am I correct in stating my damage with a dagger is 1d4-3?

I have never played a character in 5e before so I'm new to this experience.

Comment: Yikes, that must have been a bad dice roll...

Comment: Remember to mark the question as answered!

Comment: I have nothing usefult to add, just lol @ 1d4-3 damage :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**This is true for most melee weapons, but not the dagger.**

Your damage will be partially determined by the weapon you use. If you're using a quarterstaff your damage would be 1d6 - 3 (one-handed) or 1d8-3 (two-handed) thanks to its versatile property.

**Finesse weapons, such as a dagger, may use dexterity instead.**

Some melee weapons (such as the dagger) have the finesse property. For these weapons, you may use your dexterity modifier instead of your strength modifier.

**Ranged weapons use your dexterity modifier.**

If you're using a ranged weapon, such as a sling or crossbow, you'll use your dexterity modifier instead of your strength modifier.

**Spells typically do not get a damage modifier.**

If you're using a spell, the damage is based on what the spell tells you to use. If it doesn't ask for a modifier, you don't get one. Most spells that do ask for a modifier use your "spell casting modifier," which is intelligence for wizards.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that with the proper selection of cantrips, a Wizard (or other spellcaster) can often avoid having to use Strength or Dexterity at all. Ranged Spell Attacks and Melee Spell Attacks both use the casting stat.

Comment: (I'm pretty sure those *are* headings. They introduce the text that comes after and are not full sentences with full stops.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Nope. They are portions of the body of the text that I intend to emphasize. You could do them as headings, but that's not the semantics I'm going for. The bold part is basically the tldr version.

Comment: Perhaps some periods then? (Still, “the tldr version” is what headings are, classically, so we'll agree to disagree. :)

Comment: perhaps important to add that minimum damage is 1.

Comment: @Aviose I almost did, but it turns out that [isn't correct for 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/73525/77)

Comment: @AceCalhoon Wow... that's a big one that slipped by me. It also doesn't really make sense in most contexts of the game.

Comment: I'd emphasise the part about it _not_ being correct for the dagger, given that it's technically the only thing being asked. The other info is useful, but not directly answering the question.

Comment: @Aviose minimum damage is 0 in 5e - https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108178/

Comment: @enkryptor yeah, saw Ace's response. It surprises me. I bypassed that small caveat in the rules.

Comment: One small nitpick: some ranged weapons (specifically, non-finesse thrown weapons) use Strength instead of Dexterity.

Comment: @Marq Thrown weapons can be either melee or ranged weapons (light hammer vs. dart, for instance), with only the non-finesse melee using Strength (absent a feature-exception), the finesse melee using *either*, and the ranged still using Dexterity (a Dart's finesse property is only relevant when using it as an improvised melee weapon).

Comment: @AceCalhoon So... I attack my friend with my dagger and heal him for two damage (assuming I roll 1)?

Comment: @JohnHamilton I've never seen official word, but I've always assumed that it had a functional minimum of zero (like Magic: the Gathering). E.g., it isn't a pure arithmetic operation, and you can't "take away" fewer than zero hit points.

Comment: @AceCalhoon "With a penalty, it is possible to deal 0 damage, but never negative damage." It's in the "Damage Rolls" subsection of the "Damage and healing" section of Chapter 9 of the PHB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct on Page 176 under Attack Rolls and Damage it states

> You add your Strength modifier to your attack roll and your damage
>   roll when attacking with a melee weapon such as a mace, a battleaxe,
>   or a javelin.

However remember for ranged weapons on page 177 you use your dexterity bonus instead for damage

> You add your Dexterity modifier to your attack roll and your damage
>   roll when attacking with a ranged weapon, such as a sling or a
>   longbow.

Comment: But do not forget that the dagger is a finesse weapon so he has the choice of using either Strength or Dex for his damage and attack modifier.