# If I punch someone and have a -2 Strength modifier, will I technically heal the target by 1 HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, ability-scores, unarmed-combat

Unarmed strikes normally do damage equal to (1 + Str mod).

If I punch someone and have a -2 Strength modifier, will I technically heal the target by 1 HP?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73522/is-there-a-minimum-damage-rule?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 9):

## No; an unarmed strike with a negative Str mod does 0 damage

The [general rules for unarmed strikes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks) (unless overridden by a feat or racial/class/subclass feature) state:

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an **unarmed strike**: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons). **On a hit, an unarmed strike deals bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your Strength modifier.** You are proficient with your unarmed strikes.

The attack roll for an unarmed strike is (d20 + Str + proficiency bonus).

The damage is (1 + Str mod).

If you have a negative Str mod, as in your case, the result of that calculation may even be negative. However, the [rules on damage rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#DamageRolls) clarify:

> With a penalty, it is possible to deal 0 damage, but never negative damage.

Thus, the minimum possible damage on an attack is 0; you can never deal "negative damage". Any damage calculation that would result in a negative value ([after applying all relevant modifiers](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/609096374563373056)) actually results in 0 damage.