# Is there an official rule for minimum damage on a landing hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

As discussed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45603/26074), a negative modifier should always be applied to a damage roll. However, it is suggested in the [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/45604/26074) that the minimum damage should be 1.

I'd like to know if there's an official rule (or a tweet for a game developer) that can back this up?

Specifically, I'm trying to evaluate the consequences of disarming weak creatures. Would a disarmed kobold with a -2 STR modifier do 1 (1-2; minimum 1) or 0 damage (1-2; minimum 0) with an unarmed strike?

> On a hit, an **unarmed strike** deals bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your Strength modifier. (PHB, p. 195)

Comment: also related: [Do lycanthropes need to do damage...](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78815/23970). In fact, I think that one answers your question. But it's not from a dev, just from a user. (Me!)

Comment: I could have sworn I had researched the keywords "[dnd-5e] minimum damage" before posting this. My bad.

Comment: It took me a while to find it, too. That's alright--closed-as-duplicate questions perform a valuable service to the site in serving as signposts. Nothing to apologize for!